# Tiny mce very slow on large documents

Tags: performance, focus, tinymce-4

I´m doing some trials with a large document using Tiny MCE editor, but when I have a large document "charged" on it, I get a very poor performance when I try to do a "focus" action on any part of document.

Things that I´ve tried:

1 - Modify focus event on tiny MCE init (even I have tried to force script execution when a focus event arrives) doing something like this:

```
  setup: function (ed){
    ed.on('focus',function(ed, evt) {
            throw new Error("Focus stopped!");
    });
  },
```

2 - Mminify number of plug-ins that are being loadding on init.
3 - Configure tiny MCE entity encoding to "raw"

But nothing seems to provide any performance improvement.

Any idea about what could be happening with it?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Just one more "detail"... all this low performance only takes place on Firefox (v. 61 - v62 and v63), not in Chrome.... by the way there is no active spell checker on Firefox and there is no plug-in installed on it

Comment: What do you define a "large" document to be?   Perhaps you can make an example with your complete configuration on TinyMCE Fiddle of what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Large is more than 100 a4 pages.